# errors.add(:base, "MSG") without attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a problem.

I have trying to show a message without attribute.
I searched for answer's but any solution did work for me.

I want to show only error message like this:

Attachments base **não é permitido upload de .exe**

But always show this: "Attachments base". I want just to show: **não é permitido upload de .exe**

Well, in my model I have a validation:

```
     validate :suspitious_attachment

private

def suspitious_attachment
if ends_with? '.bat', '.com', '.exe', '.src', '.cmd'
  errors.add(:base, I18n.t('errors.messages.suspitious_attachment', :value => attachment.path[-4..-1]))
end
end

def ends_with?(*args)
args.each do |arg|
  return true if attachment.path.ends_with? arg
end
false
end
```

In my view:

```
<% if @issue.errors[:attachments].any? %>
  <div class="clearfix error">
  <% else %>
  <div class="clearfix">
  <% end %>
    <label>
      <%= image_tag 'icons/required.png', :alt => '*' %><%= t('labels.attachments') %>
      </label>
   <div class="input">
   <div class="inputs-list">
    <%= f.fields_for :attachments do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'attachment_fields', :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.link_to_add t("actions.add_another_attachment"), :attachments, :class => "icon-attach" %>
    <% if @issue.errors[:attachments].any? %>
        <%= content_tag :span, t('errors.messages.blank'), class: 'help-inline error' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my views/layout/_error_messages.html.erb

```
<% if target.errors.any? %>
<% if target.errors.any? %>
     <div class="alert-message fade in warning">
<a class="close" href="#">×</a>
<p><%= target.errors.full_messages.first %></p>
</div><% end %>
```

I tried:

```
errors[:base] << I18n.t('errors.messages.suspitious_attachment', :value => attachment.path[-4..-1]))
```

and

```
errors.add_to_base(I18n.t('errors.messages.suspitious_attachment', :value => attachment.path[-4..-1]))
```

I tried to insert in my translate file:

```
activerecord:
  errors:
    format: "%{message}"
```

Someone can help me? 
Sorry for my english.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [#add_to_base](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Errors/add_to_base) instead:

```
def suspitious_attachment
  if ends_with? '.bat', '.com', '.exe', '.src', '.cmd'
    errors.add_to_base(I18n.t('errors.messages.suspitious_attachment', :value => attachment.path[-4..-1]))
  end
end
```